# Segmentation fault: 11 - C function

Tags: c++, nvcc

I have "segmentation fault:11" with this code, and I can't find a solution

```
static const int N = 512;
static const int M = 64;
static const int K = sizeof(int) * 8;
static const int SZ = N*M / K;

void readFromFile(int *v);

int main(void){
    int v[SZ];
    readFromFile(v);
 }

void readFromFile(int *v) {
    ifstream f;
    f.open("...path/file.txt");
    char c = f.get();
    int i = 0;
    while (f.good()) {
       v[i] = c - '0';
       c = f.get();
       i++;
   }
   f.close();
}
```

I have an int array and a file used to fill the array. 
It's a piece of code used to fill int array for cuda computing.
I'm using nsight and nvcc.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Really is this the real code ?

Comment: Please include the relevant code, specifically the computation in `f` and the definition of `N`.

Comment: CUDA may be a bit over your head if you're having trouble with this.  Run your code through valgrind to get more details on where you are going out of bounds `valgrind ./a.out`

Comment: You should Turn on your compiler settings and see what exactly is **static const int SZ = N*M / K;**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code says `N = 512` and you declare `v` as `int v[N];` 
But if your file has more character than `N` then `i` get bigger than `N` and segmentation fault generate as you access invalid index of `v`.

```
int i = 0;
while (f.good()) {
   v[i] = c - '0';
   c = f.get();
   i++;                    //No checking if it is greater than N
}
```

Actually it's better to use like

```
char c;
int i = 0;
while ((c=f.get())!=EOF) {
   v[i] = c - '0';
   i++;
}
```

And you should also check limit of `i` for further error minimization.

Comment: Dimensions are the same. I added a print into readFromFile but execution end before call the function.

Comment: Initialize array more than that, might some white space cause problem. You can put some small amount character in file to debug.